# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gpiozero'

Tags: python, gpiozero

I tried to use gpiozero on my raspberry pi 4, when i try to run the code it doesn't find the module.

Any suggestions?

I tried downloading it by several different ways as stated on the gpiozero documentation page. Don't know what to do now.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you should try

```
pip install gpiozero
```

if u have python with two or more versions, please consider an environment